# Why resolve is undefined within callback of request?

Tags: node.js

When i run code given below in terminal than i get following error:-
ReferenceError: resolve is not defined.

```js
const request = require('request');

let geoLocationPromise = (zipCode) => {
return new Promise(()=>{
  request({
    url:`https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${zipCode}`,
    JSON: true
  }, (error, response, body)=>{
      if(error){
        reject('Unable to connect to server');
      }else if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body);
        resolve(JSON.parse(body.currently, undefined, 2));
      }
  });
});
};

geoLocationPromise(841101).then((loc)=>{
  console.log(loc);
}, (errorMessage)=>{
  console.log(errorMessage);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the parameters “reject” and “resolve” for your Promise's callback, like this:

```js
const request = require('request');

let geoLocationPromise = (zipCode) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  request({
    url:`https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${zipCode}`,
    JSON: true
  }, (error, response, body)=>{
      if(error){
        reject('Unable to connect to server');
      }else if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body);
        resolve(JSON.parse(body.currently, undefined, 2));
      }
  });
});
};
```